# Creating 'non-embedded' DATADOG graphs in Node/Express Application

Tags: node.js, api, express, graph, datadog

I'm attempting to query our DATADOG hub and display some metric graphs.  However, it appears the default way to do this is using an embed script generated by DATADOG and utilizing that in your app.  I'm actually wanting to draw the graphs on my side, using their API data so I'm better able to control the size, look and flexibility of the graphs.

Is this something that is possible? Rather new to DATADOG and everything seems to be done in an iFrame, which I do not want.

Additionally, I found a package which I believe may be of use for Node?: http://brettlangdon.github.io/node-dogapi/#embed-create

D.D. Graphs Docs: http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#graphs

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I have not seen anything similar on S.O.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you actually want is the metrics-query API endpoint? http://docs.datadoghq.com/api/#metrics-query

There are also a few Node.JS libraries that may be able to handle this kind of metric querying for you: http://docs.datadoghq.com/libraries/#community-node

Comment: Interesting, but isn't that going to give me the raw data? How would that thrn be graphed?

Comment: Oh, yeah, that would just give you the raw data. I thought that's what you wanted when you said "I'm actually wanting to draw the graphs on my side, using their API data so I'm better able to control the size, look...". I imagine there's some node libraries around that might help make those graphs from the raw data though

Comment: Good point. I guess what I'm really looking for is a way to have data dog draw the graphs on the client side instead of creating them there and just embedding a frame..

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure Datadog doesn't offer that. It may not be very hard to just have the results from a metric query API fill into a graphing library, though. I bet [D3](https://d3js.org/) would work pretty well.